# Error while running Selenium with Chrome in Docker

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to deploy a Python script in a docker container that utilizes Selenium ChromeWebDriver:

```
def initialize_driver(self):
        try:
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument("--headless")
            options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
            options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),  options=options)
            return driver
        except Exception as error:
            logging.error("INITIAL:",error)
```

However, i encountered the following error message:

> Logging error ---
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/file_manager.py", line 65, in __extract_zip
>
> archive.extractall(to_directory)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1677, in extractall
>
> self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1732, in _extract_member
>
> shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 197, in copyfileobj
>
> buf = fsrc_read(length)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 951, in read
>
> data = self._read1(n)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1019, in _read1
>
> data += self._read2(n - len(data))
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1054, in _read2
>
> raise EOFError
>
> EOFError
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/app/newsarticle.py", line 122, in initialize_driver
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),  options=options)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/chrome.py", line 40, in install
>
> driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/manager.py", line 41, in _get_driver_binary_path
>
> binary_path = self._cache_manager.save_file_to_cache(driver, file)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver_cache.py", line 54, in save_file_to_cache
>
> files = self.unpack_archive(archive, path)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver_cache.py", line 49, in unpack_archive
>
> return self._file_manager.unpack_archive(archive, path)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/file_manager.py", line 57, in unpack_archive
>
> return self.__extract_zip(archive_file, target_dir)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/file_manager.py", line 67, in __extract_zip
>
> if e.args[0] not in [26, 13] and e.args[1] not in [
>
> ```
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 1110, in emit
>
> msg = self.format(record)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 953, in format
>
> return fmt.format(record)
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 687, in format
>
> record.message = record.getMessage()
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 377, in getMessage
>
> msg = msg % self.args
>
> ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>
> Call stack:
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 995, in _bootstrap
>
> self._bootstrap_inner()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
> ```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.2
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app 
RUN apt -f install
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install bzip2 -y && apt-get install unzip -y

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt 
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt 
CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

My requirements.txt:

````
selenium
packaging
webdriver_manager
chromedriver-binary```
````

I tried to add

```
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils
```

to the Dockerfile but that didn't change anything. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that i downloaded the wrong version of the chromedriver in the dockerfile.